# Testing for independence in clustered cross-sectional data

Tags: multiple-regression, autocorrelation, independence, cross-section, durbin-watson-test

I am developing a multiple regression model using Expert-survey data on different ideological positions of political parties in Europe. So my dataset contains >200 political parties with different quasi-metric variables. As there are (in theory at least) two levels in my data (Countries and parties) I want to find out if errors are independent / residual terms are uncorrelated.

As the Durbin-Watson-Test isn't suitable for my data because there is no particular order of cases, I wanted to ask whether someone knows a different way of testing for independent errors in clustered cross-sectional data?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in the answer, my supervisor suggested this simple method to account for potential variation on the country level and see if observations on party-level are independent:

I simply added countries as dummy-variables to my regression model.

Looking at the coefficients and comparing them to the model without countries as dummy-variables should show if there is any significant variation or if the single (party-level) observations are or aren't independent of the country-level. If the coefficients and their significance don't change substantially this should be a sign for independent observations.